# Reading data disks in Xbox360 homebrew

Tags: xbox360, homebrew

I heard that X360 homebrews are not allowed to be started from DVDs; however, they can be downloaded from PC or via live and started.

The question is: it is disabled to access DVD drive at all?

I want to access data tracks, without using any (theoretically [prohibited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237525/438039)) media APIs for playbacks; also I don't want to *run from disk* (which is [prohibited](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/8399/122831.aspx) by Microsoft).

Comment: Your question refers to "homebrew" development, but your links reference XNA. "Homebrew" development usually refers to development with unofficially sanctioned toolchains, so XNA wouldn't qualify -- are you using XNA or not?

Comment: @JoshPetrie, I didn't knew that Xbox360 homebrew isnt limited to XNA now and allows to run a complete Linux on the box, thanks, would continue the research from here (as it was told in the answer below that XNA had disabled DVD access completely). Do you have any tips in the direction of the unofficial homebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean XNA, you can't deploy your game on a disc

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/8399/122831.aspx

or read data from a disc

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/14886.aspx